# Good resources to start python for web development?

Tags: python

I'm really interested in learning Python for web development. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been looking at stuff on Google, but haven't really found anything that shows proper documentation and how to get started. Any recommended frameworks? Tutorials?

I've been doing PHP for 5 years now, so I just want to try something new.

Comment: try google appspot with python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django is probably the best starting point. It's got great documentation and an easy tutorial (at http://djangoproject.com/) and a free online book too (http://www.djangobook.com/).

Comment: This may be pushing it, but does Google App Engine support django?

Comment: django isn't my favorite for production, but it has all the major components that you'll need to become familiar with, and an amazing wealth of great tutorials.

Comment: Yes, App Engine supports Django 0.96, 1.0, and 1.1 at this time: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django

Answer (score 2):

**Web Server Gateway Interface**

About

- http://www.wsgi.org/en/latest/index.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface

Tutorials

- http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial
- http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2007/5/21/getting-started-with-wsgi/
- http://archimedeanco.com/wsgi-tutorial/

Comment: can you please give me a detailed tutorial or something for WSGI? Cuz I found the links for WSGI hard to understand.

Comment: WSGI is an interface that middleware is expected to conform to maximize win.

Comment: @Alcott Try this chapter of the webob docs http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/do-it-yourself.html when I happened upon it a couple of years ago, a lot of things about wsgi became very clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are three major parts to python web frameworks, in my experience. From the front to back:

**Views/Templates:** Application frameworks don't function as independent scripts - instead, you map paths to python functions or objects which return html. To generate the html you probably need templates (aka views). Check out [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/docs/users_guide_html/).

**Application framework/Server:** There are plenty. [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) is my favorite, and is good for understanding how a python application server works because **a)** it's simple and **b)** unlike [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and others, it is just the application server and doesn't include a templating engine or a database abstraction layer.

**Database layer:** I've actually never used it, but everyone seems to like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). I prefer, in simple applications, executing SQL directly using a tool like [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) (for postgres).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Django. It's easy to learn, and it works with GAE (though the default version is 0.96, a little bit old, but you can change it). And there's a video about [rapid development](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1gTI4BOPUw) (by Guido Van Rossum) that goes through the basics of setting up a Django project in App Engine.

Comment: GAE support for Django is a bit outdated but not *that* bad. It can run 0.96, 1.0, and 1.1, but not 1.2 yet. See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django