# python database search with html

Tags: python, html, database, search

I have created a database with python and the results are kept in a text file.
I would like to create a simple html with a search button that looks through my database.
My database would be accessible only on my computer.

My database looks something like this:

```
Reference | Name | Dimension
XXX         AAA     45
```

So, for example, if I search for a specific reference I would like to obtain their name or dimension obviously.

Is this even possible with python and where do I start ?
I should mention I have basic skills in html and python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this:

- Install a webserver on your local machine and write a full-fledged [Python web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154921/good-resources-to-start-python-for-web-development)
- Write a simple webserver and application in Python using [`BaseHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html)
- Write an HTML/JavaScript application that doesn't use Python at all and parses the file for itself. Note that due to recently tightened restrictions, this may still require being served by a webserver.
- Write a Python application that writes the database to a JavaScript file. While this is inflexible (you need to run it every time you want to update the database), it's also very simple - just encode your data with [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) and write it in a JavaScript file or element, like this.

```
htmlfile = open('database.html', 'w')
htmlfile.write('<html>...')
htmlfile.write('<script>var db = ' + json.encode(database) + ';</script>');
```

Either way, you're going to have to write HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Alternative to the first option: write a simple webserver in Python, using the HTTP server in the standard library. Examples are all over the web, for example, http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php

Comment: @Balir Thanks - integrated into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a very simple use case and if you already have a web server installed, then probably the simplest and quickest way is to use a CGI script written in python. Check out the cgi module: http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html.

Basically you have to handle GET request to show a HTML form for asking the query string and the POST request to process the query and show the results.